# How to convert elements of an string to a pack format (ex: '123-56.2' -> b'\x01\x02\x03\x0-...'

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte

I want to make a bytes variable that I can unpack it using a specific format. (I want to "store" data to a memory like format (C struct type) and then extract the information using a rule)
The input data is a string array that contains number characters like: `'1', '2',..`, respectively `'-'` and  `'.'`, witch I am using to represent float/double variables.

I tried to used `bytes.fromhex()`, but it doesn't suport `'-'` and `'.'` char.

Tried:

```
msg = '212120121-70.43'
print(bytes.fromhex(msg))
```

output:

```
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 9. ('-' char is on that position).
```

I'm looking for the best solution that can help me.
Thanks!!

Comment: How flexible a solution do you need? Is it always in the xxx-xx.xx format? Is there a limit to the length of the first number part? [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) probably works if it has a predictable format.

Comment: Yes. The format are : 'B','H','H','B' (using the pack format => there are 8 characters on the first part) and then are some parameters, witch can be float, negative, integers, uint8_t. Flexibility can appear on the parameter side.

Comment: I see,so there can be multiple extra parameter? How do you tell where one ends and another begins from the string and what type you want it to be in? And you do it to save space or for what reason?

Comment: I have a dictionary. The string represent a "command"  that I defined ( I am working on a radio communication app and I use some commands for change information). Every comand have specific types of parameters. So, depends of the comand that I used, I know how much parameters I need and what type they are, using the dictionary. The type of comand is in the first part. ( the last char of 'B' type).